# Why is template<classTp> bool is_array<Tp[]> a partial specialization for template<class T> bool is_array<Tp>?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

How to comprehend that `template<typename Tp> bool is_array<Tp[]> = true` is a partial specialization for `template<typename T> bool is_array<Tp> = true`?

Here is the related [code snippet:](https://godbolt.org/z/G6jdsn)

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
bool is_array = false;

template<typename Tp>
bool is_array<Tp[]> = true;

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_array<int> << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_array<int[]> << std::endl;
}
```

I've also noticed that generally speaking, the number of template parameters in the partial template specialization is less than the number of template parameters in the primary template.

The partial specializations often are seen like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/5nxWMr):

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename T, typename U>
class add
{
public:
    add(T x, U y)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename U>
class add<int, U>
{
    public:
    add(int x, U y)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;       
    }
};

int main()
{
    add<int, double>(1, 5.0);
    add<char, int>('a', 9);
}
```

Comment: Image that `T` is `Tp[]`, like `T = int[]`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking exactly. Are you unclear about the rules of partial template specialization?

Comment: @cigien I'm reasonably sure John is asking why the array version is considered a specialization, i.e. not selecting is_array = false;

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Yes, sorry for my poor English. My question is why the array version is considered a specialization. And **generally** speaking, **the number of template parameters** in the partial template specialization is **less** than the primary one.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to address the part about the number of template parameters as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a template to be a *specialization* of a *primary*, it needs to be more specialized than the primary. This basically means that the specialization must match a *strict subset* of types that the primary can match.

In your case, the specialization would match `int[]`, `char[]`, etc. The primary would also match these types, but the primary would additionally match types like `int`, `char`, `std::vector<std::string>` etc.

When specifying a template argument like this `is_array<int[]>`, the rules say that the specialization is tried first. In this case, `Tp[]` can be matched to `int[]` (basically by substituting `int` for `Tp`) and so the specialization is chosen.

When specifying a template argument like this `is_array<int>`, the  specialization is tried first, but it fails to match. So then the primary is tried, and that matches, so the primary template is chosen.

As you've mentioned, it is often the case that the specialization has fewer template parameters. This is not necessary, so long as the rule I mentioned above is applicable, i.e. the specialization must match a strict subset of the types that can be matched by the primary.

In fact, the specialization can even have more template parameters than the primary. Again, the requirement is only that the specialization match a subset of types matched by the primary.

Comment: This rule is described at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization under Partial ordering.

"Formally, to establish more-specialized-than relationship between partial specializations, each is first converted to a fictitious function template as follows:..."

Answer (score 2):

Here is intermediate output generated by compiler for your code (reference [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/))

Compiler is using the specialized template for arrays.

```cpp
template<typename T>
bool is_array = false;

template<>
bool is_array<int> = false;
template<>
bool is_array<int []> = true;

template<typename Tp>
bool is_array<Tp[]> = true;

int main()
{
  std::cout.operator<<(is_array<int>).operator<<(std::endl);
  std::cout.operator<<(is_array<int []>).operator<<(std::endl);
}
```

Now if removed the below code

```cpp
template<typename Tp>
bool is_array<Tp[]> = true;
```

compiler will generate

```cpp
template<typename T>
bool is_array = false;

template<>
bool is_array<int> = false;
template<>
bool is_array<int []> = false;

int main()
{
  std::cout.operator<<(is_array<int>).operator<<(std::endl);
  std::cout.operator<<(is_array<int []>).operator<<(std::endl);
}
```

You can see that compiler simply replaced `T` with `int[]` which is nothing but the second template provided by you, a specialized one.

Comment: I think there is no partial specialization in the first code snippet(in your answer). It's a full specialization indeed.

Answer (score 2):

The specialization can even have more template parameters than the primary. Here is an [example](https://godbolt.org/z/jfq6G7):

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
bool is_array = false;
    
template <typename Tp, int N>
bool is_array<Tp[N]> = true;

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_array<int> << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_array<int[5]> << std::endl;
}
```